# Is there any way to return a result set (of different tables) from a stored procedure / function

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures, plpgsql

I want to fetch data from more than 1 table on a single go. Is there any way to return a result set (of different tables) from a stored procedure / function?

Answer (score 0):

The dynamic [`refcursor`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-cursors.html) can be used:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo(tabname character varying)
 RETURNS refcursor
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare r refcursor;
begin
  open r for execute format('select * from %I', tabname);
  return r;
end;
$function$

(2022-12-09 06:41:42) postgres=# begin;
BEGIN
(2022-12-09 06:42:12) postgres=# select foo('pg_class');
┌────────────────────┐
│        foo         │
╞════════════════════╡
│ <unnamed portal 1> │
└────────────────────┘
(1 row)

(2022-12-09 06:42:35) postgres=# fetch 10 from "<unnamed portal 1>";
┌──────┬─────────────────────┬──────────────┬─────────┬───────────┬──────────┬───────┬─────────────┬───────────────┬──────────┬───────────┬─────
│ oid  │       relname       │ relnamespace │ reltype │ reloftype │ relowner │ relam │ relfilenode │ reltablespace │ relpages │ reltuples │ rela
╞══════╪═════════════════════╪══════════════╪═════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪═══════╪═════════════╪═══════════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═════
│ 2619 │ pg_statistic        │           11 │   10029 │         0 │       10 │     2 │        2619 │             0 │       19 │       407 │     
│ 1247 │ pg_type             │           11 │      71 │         0 │       10 │     2 │           0 │             0 │       15 │       611 │     
│ 2836 │ pg_toast_1255       │           99 │       0 │         0 │       10 │     2 │           0 │             0 │        1 │         3 │     
│ 2837 │ pg_toast_1255_index │           99 │       0 │         0 │       10 │   403 │           0 │             0 │        1 │         0 │     
│ 4171 │ pg_toast_1247       │           99 │       0 │         0 │       10 │     2 │           0 │             0 │        0 │         0 │     
│ 4172 │ pg_toast_1247_index │           99 │       0 │         0 │       10 │   403 │           0 │             0 │        1 │         0 │     
│ 2830 │ pg_toast_2604       │           99 │       0 │         0 │       10 │     2 │        2830 │             0 │        0 │         0 │     
│ 2831 │ pg_toast_2604_index │           99 │       0 │         0 │       10 │   403 │        2831 │             0 │        1 │         0 │     
│ 2832 │ pg_toast_2606       │           99 │       0 │         0 │       10 │     2 │        2832 │             0 │        0 │         0 │     
│ 2833 │ pg_toast_2606_index │           99 │       0 │         0 │       10 │   403 │        2833 │             0 │        1 │         0 │     
└──────┴─────────────────────┴──────────────┴─────────┴───────────┴──────────┴───────┴─────────────┴───────────────┴──────────┴───────────┴─────
(10 rows)
(2022-12-09 06:43:31) postgres=# close "<unnamed portal 1>";
CLOSE CURSOR
(2022-12-09 06:43:54) postgres=# select foo('pg_proc');
┌────────────────────┐
│        foo         │
╞════════════════════╡
│ <unnamed portal 2> │
└────────────────────┘
(1 row)

(2022-12-09 06:44:03) postgres=# fetch 3 from "<unnamed portal 2>";
┌──────┬─────────┬──────────────┬──────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────────┬────────────┬─────────┬───────────┬──────────────┬──────
│ oid  │ proname │ pronamespace │ proowner │ prolang │ procost │ prorows │ provariadic │ prosupport │ prokind │ prosecdef │ proleakproof │ prois
╞══════╪═════════╪══════════════╪══════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════════╪════════════╪═════════╪═══════════╪══════════════╪══════
│ 1242 │ boolin  │           11 │       10 │      12 │       1 │       0 │           0 │ -          │ f       │ f         │ f            │ t    
│ 1243 │ boolout │           11 │       10 │      12 │       1 │       0 │           0 │ -          │ f       │ f         │ f            │ t    
│ 1244 │ byteain │           11 │       10 │      12 │       1 │       0 │           0 │ -          │ f       │ f         │ f            │ t    
└──────┴─────────┴──────────────┴──────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────────┴────────────┴─────────┴───────────┴──────────────┴──────
(3 rows)
(2022-12-09 06:44:16) postgres=# close "<unnamed portal 2>";
CLOSE CURSOR
(2022-12-09 06:44:21) postgres=# commit;
COMMIT
```

for more cursors:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.foo2(tabname1 character varying, tabname2 character varying)
 RETURNS SETOF refcursor
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
declare r refcursor;
begin
  open r for execute format('select * from %I', tabname1);
  return next r;
  r := NULL; -- re initialize refcursor
  open r for execute format('select * from %I', tabname2);
  return next r;
end;
$function$

(2022-12-09 06:58:33) postgres=# begin;
BEGIN
(2022-12-09 06:58:36) postgres=# select * from foo2('pg_class', 'pg_proc');
┌────────────────────┐
│        foo2        │
╞════════════════════╡
│ <unnamed portal 5> │
│ <unnamed portal 6> │
└────────────────────┘
(2 rows)

(2022-12-09 06:58:39) postgres=# fetch 2 from "<unnamed portal 5>";
┌──────┬──────────────┬──────────────┬─────────┬───────────┬──────────┬───────┬─────────────┬───────────────┬──────────┬───────────┬────────────
│ oid  │   relname    │ relnamespace │ reltype │ reloftype │ relowner │ relam │ relfilenode │ reltablespace │ relpages │ reltuples │ relallvisib
╞══════╪══════════════╪══════════════╪═════════╪═══════════╪══════════╪═══════╪═════════════╪═══════════════╪══════════╪═══════════╪════════════
│ 2619 │ pg_statistic │           11 │   10029 │         0 │       10 │     2 │        2619 │             0 │       19 │       407 │            
│ 1247 │ pg_type      │           11 │      71 │         0 │       10 │     2 │           0 │             0 │       15 │       611 │            
└──────┴──────────────┴──────────────┴─────────┴───────────┴──────────┴───────┴─────────────┴───────────────┴──────────┴───────────┴────────────
(2 rows)
(2022-12-09 06:58:47) postgres=# fetch 2 from "<unnamed portal 6>";
┌──────┬─────────┬──────────────┬──────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────┬─────────────┬────────────┬─────────┬───────────┬──────────────┬──────
│ oid  │ proname │ pronamespace │ proowner │ prolang │ procost │ prorows │ provariadic │ prosupport │ prokind │ prosecdef │ proleakproof │ prois
╞══════╪═════════╪══════════════╪══════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════╪═════════════╪════════════╪═════════╪═══════════╪══════════════╪══════
│ 1242 │ boolin  │           11 │       10 │      12 │       1 │       0 │           0 │ -          │ f       │ f         │ f            │ t    
│ 1243 │ boolout │           11 │       10 │      12 │       1 │       0 │           0 │ -          │ f       │ f         │ f            │ t    
└──────┴─────────┴──────────────┴──────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────┴─────────────┴────────────┴─────────┴───────────┴──────────────┴──────
(2 rows)
(2022-12-09 06:58:53) postgres=# commit;
COMMIT
```

Cursor is an pointer to open (in execution) query. refcursor value is some handle of some cursor in string format. You can specify own name or you PLpgSQL generates unique name, when the refcursor variable is NULL (when it is used inside `OPEN` statement).